# Chinese punctuation problem

Tags: punctuation, xecjk

I am trying to move a Chinese punctuation mark to the head of a character. I am using the following macro, which works fine. But if I redefine the `\CJKpunctsymbol`, it will be a messy. Can any one help me on this?

works fine code - which directly apply to a punctuation:

```
\hskip -0.9em \vbox to 0.1em {\vskip -1em{\hbox to 0.9em {。}}}
```

Redefine `\CJKpunctsymbol` - the `\hbox` will be very long and can't resize.

```
\def\vCJKpunctsymbol#1{\hskip -0.9em \vbox to 0.1em {\vskip -1em {\hbox to 0.9em {\CJKsymbol{#1}}}}}
\let\CJKpunctsymbol\vCJKpunctsymbol
```

The following 2 pictures are examples. I use `\fbox` to make it clear.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. It would be helpful to add a complete compilable example document that includes the code fragments you post. This will make it easier for people to play around with your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For old-style punctuation (句读), I think it can be defined like this:

```
\catcode`。\active
\def。{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hskip-.25em\raisebox{1ex}{\string。}}}
```

No `xeCJK` punctuation features should be used, since the current version of `xeCJK` does not support vertical typesetting properly.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont[RawFeature={script=hani:language=CHN:vertical:+valt}]{SimSun}

\catcode`。\active
\def。{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hskip-.25em\raisebox{1ex}{\string。}}}
\catcode`、\active
\def、{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hskip-.25em\raisebox{1ex}{\string、}}}

\begin{document}

\rotatebox{-90}{%
子曰。学而时习之、不亦说乎。}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\makebox[0pt][l]` is the same as `\rlap`.

Comment: A simpler way to do the same is with `newunicodechar`: `\newunicodechar{。}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hskip-.25em\raisebox{1ex}{。}}}` (you don't even need `\string`)